# Definite integral impossible but indefinite possible

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do a spherical integral in *Mathematica*:

```
f[θ_, ϕ_] = (k^4 Cos[θ]^2 Cot[β] Csc[β] Sin[θ]^3 Sin[ϕ]^2)/(
  4 (1 + k Cos[θ]) (1 + k Cos[β] Cos[θ] + k Cos[ϕ] Sin[β] Sin[θ])) + 
  (k^4 Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] Csc[β] Sin[θ]^4 Sin[ϕ]^2)/(
  4 (1 + k Cos[θ]) (1 + k Cos[β] Cos[θ] + k Cos[ϕ] Sin[β] Sin[θ]))
```

If I try the following:

```
Integrate[f[θ, ϕ], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

*Mathematica* does not produce an answer. However, if I try to do an analytical integral like this:

```
g[θ_] = Integrate[f[θ, ϕ], ϕ]
```

I get an answer very quickly, and that answer differentiates to the integrand I started with. Now I can evaluate the value of the integral I am trying to find by doing:

```
g[2 π] - g[0]
```

My question is twofold:

1. Why is this happening in Mathematica? I assume it is because the algorithms for finding a definite and indefinite integrals are different.
2. Is this a valid way of doing the integral in this case (and others)? I am asking because the end result does not agree with a purely numerical integral over the sphere, and this might be the source of error.

Comment: "I assume it is because the algorithms for finding a definite and indefinite integrals are different." - yes, it has to worry about branch cuts and such, since *Mathematica* assumes everything is complex unless told otherwise. You might wish to look up `Assuming[]`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M., I know one needs to use assumptions. For the above integral I have tried:
Assumptions -> {k > 0 && 
   k < 1 && \[Beta] >= 0 && \[Beta] <= \[Pi] && \[Theta] >= 
    0 && \[Theta] <= \[Pi] && 
   k \[Element] Reals && \[Beta] \[Element] 
    Reals && \[Theta] \[Element] Reals}
but it hasn't helped much.

Comment: To simplify matters slightly: if you put in a condition like `0 < k <1`, then you don't need to put in `k ∈ Reals`, since your use of the inequality already imposes that condition.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you just weren't patient enough.  After 12.5 minutes, version 11.1.1 gives me an answer.  Not a beautfiul one, but not a ridiculuous one, either. We've made this better in 11.2.  It takes it a little over a minute to come up with a simpler answer.

Re 1): It might use different methods for definite and indefinite integration (e.g., residues aren't of much use for indefinite integrals).  It could also be that it's checking that the antiderivative is is continuous over the interval of integration / trying to patch pieces together to find a continuous one.  Without really going into the guts of Integrate, I couldn't tell you which.

Re 2): Given 1, that's dangerous.  Not to claim that Integrate is perfect, but if it could do the integral by a simple application of the fundamental theorem, it probably would have, so you should check such answers carefully.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. In fact I realised why this happens in the meantime. But one thing I want to ask you: 11.2? When is it going to be released?

Comment: For a wonderful explanation for why you sometimes can't say Integrate[f[x],{x,a,b}] = F[b] - F[a] read   http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/11/08/mathematica-qa-series-surprises-in-differentiation-and-integration/    other issues with integration are discussed at   http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/11/08/mathematica-qa-series-surprises-in-differentiation-and-integration/

Comment: Additionally there is also [this blog entry](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) by Oleksandr Pavlyk.

Comment: To quote Robert X Cringly: "`Real Soon Now', a computer industry expression meaning `In this lifetime, maybe`".   :)  I cannot give any date certain, but we have had a couple of pre-releases to beta testers, and we're fixing some critical bugs discovered in the process.  So hopefully in the fairly near future.

Comment: @Itai, I see; [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) it is, then… :)

Comment: @ItaiSeggev thank you. Mathematica 11.1 gave me a very confusing answer, one that involves Arg[] (even though everything is real), and Floor[], which is not the kind of function I expected here. Is it possible to get a 11.2 beta? Or, alternatively, would you share with us the simpler answer it returned?

Comment: @Morgan, with the caveat that I haven't actually tried running this particular integral: sometimes, real results require complex functions/numbers to represent them. A classical example would be the *casus irreducibilis* of solving cubic equations.

Comment: @J.M. I agree with you, however the argument of the `Arg[]` function in the answer is a purely real number. I have specified assumptions for the ranges of the variables, and explicitly that all of them are real.

Comment: @Morgan, in that specific case of real argument, $\arg$ can only evaluate to either $0$ or $\pi$. Unfortunately, `FullSimplify[]` will not convert the `Arg[]` to an appropriate `Piecewise[]` expression.

Comment: I am not even sure that Mathematica is handling this Arg[] very well internally (or I could be wrong, of course). I am eager to see the simpler solution that would be given by 11.2, though.